# Create a loop for naming new data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I split an existing data frame into smaller data frames of sizes of 100. In a next step, I want to name all of those data frames so that all data frames have specific names:

This should look the following way: df1 should have the first 100 entries, followed by df2 with 101-201 and so on, how can I do that?

I thought of something like:

```
for i in range(0,len(df_total)):
   paste("df",i,sep="") = df_total[i]
```

Unfortunately I always get the following error message: **cannot assign to function call**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to with `paste("df",i,sep="") = df_total[i]`?

Comment: df_total[1] is one data frame with 100 entries, I want it to be named df1, df_total[2] is another data frame with 100 entries and I want it to be named df2, and so on

Comment: So, you just want to create individual variables out of the list of dataframes?

Comment: Yes, each data frame should have an individual name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: I looked through it, but I still cannot solve my problem..

Comment: Any time you find yourself wanting a series of multiple variables like `df1`, `df2`, etc, you probably want to use a `list` or `dict` instead.  I suggest you read through the thread that @ThePyGuy posted again.

Answer (score 1):

So, `df_total` is the list of dataframes right?
Just iterate it using `enumerate`, then assign the global variable using `globals`:

```py
for idx,df in enumerate(df_total, 1):
    globals()[f'df{idx}'] = df
```

Please be noted that creating variable like this is not a recommended way, if you need to have reference by name, you can always use a dictionary:

```py
dfs = {}
for idx,df in enumerate(df_total, 1):
    dfs[f'df{idx}'] = df
```

You can later access the dataframes in dictionaries like `dfs['df1'], dfs['df2'], ...` so on.